Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot and make use of the WINDOWS-ROOT trust store type
I am trying to enable HTTPS in my Spring Boot application and make use of the WINDOWS-ROOT trust store type.
I need this so that my Spring Boot application will act as a client and call another application.
When my Spring Boot application acts as server, HTTPS works as expected with the below configuration in the application.properties file:
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=.
server.ssl.key-store-type=WINDOWS-MY
server.ssl.client-auth=need 

When I add configuration for the trust store type, it doesn't work:
server.port=11443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=.
server.ssl.key-store-type=WINDOWS-MY
server.ssl.trust-store=.
server.ssl.trust-store-type=WINDOWS-ROOT
server.ssl.client-auth=need

Any idea how it can work for WINDOWS-ROOT trust store type, when my Spring Boot application acts as client?

...it doesn't work:.. Please provide a better, more detailed description of any  errors or anomalous behavior you have encountered

This is the error I get: “An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine”

I don't really know Spring Boot, but judging by the names of stuff I'd guess that everything that starts out as server.ssl. is just for incoming connections. In  particular, server.ssl.client-auth=need likely is configuring your server to require TLS client authentication, which mean clients connecting to you must have their own certificate. And server.ssl.trust-store-type=WINDOWS-ROOT probably indicates which CAs your server trusts to sign these clients' certificates. You can find out more by examining your server with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/.
